# Why does this email send to local gmail address but not to att.net address?

Tags: c#, email, gmail, email-attachments, smtpclient

I have some code that sends an email and attachment to two email addresses: a "local" gmail address (my work email, which has a ucsc.edu suffix and which I access via https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox) and a "remote" email address (my personal email, an att.net account).

The following code works perfectly for sending the email to my local/"gmail" account, but I do not receive the email in my personal att.net account:

```
public static void SendEmailWithAttachment(string fileToMail, String from, String to, String subj, String body)
{
    String server = GetSMTPHostName();
    string file = fileToMail;

    MailMessage message = new MailMessage(
       from,
       to,
       subj,
       body);

    Attachment data = new Attachment(file, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
    ContentDisposition disposition = data.ContentDisposition;
    disposition.CreationDate = System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(file);
    disposition.ModificationDate = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(file);
    disposition.ReadDate = System.IO.File.GetLastAccessTime(file);
    message.Attachments.Add(data);

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server);
    client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

    try
    {
        client.Send(message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in SendEmailWithAttachment(): {0}", ex.ToString());
    }
    data.Dispose();
    message.Dispose();
}
```

The arguments sent to this method are exactly the same in both cases, except for the "to" value (the email recipient). Even in the case where I receive no email, the client.Send(message) line "works" - the catch block is not entered. But it works in the same way a Congressman works - it *claims* to have succeeded, but nothing is actually accomplished.

What is necessary to get this email to "cross the Rubicon"?

Comment: Check your spam/junk folders?

Comment: Yep, nothing in spam, or trash, or anywhere visible.

Comment: Sometimes an ISP will decide that a sender is just plain bad and will not even deliver email to the junk folder, but rather will outright block it.  Sometimes Gmail's SMTP servers would get such a notification during the Gmail to AT&T SMTP conversation (which I do not believe Gmail exposes to you), and sometimes you would just silently be blocked.  You might have run into this for example if you did something while testing your code to send a whole lot of junk to the att.net domain.  Try a non-AT&T email (e.g. sign up for Hotmail).